# FlatMapFunction does not define a serialversionUid

Tags: java, apache-spark

[image]

```
@Component("loader")
    @Slf4j
    public class LoaderSpark implements Serializable , SparkJob {
            private static final int MAX_VERSIONS = 1;
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5911491576792653184L;
           spark.sparkContext().getConf().toDebugString());
          HBaseUtil hBaseUtil = new HBaseUtil(props);

        byte[][] prefixes = new byte[][]{toBytes("document"),
                toBytes("dataSource"),
                toBytes("hold:")};

        Filter filter = new MultipleColumnPrefixFilter(prefixes);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(toBytes("data"));        
        scan.setFilter(filter);

    @Override
    public void run(final SparkSession spark, final String... args) {

        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> ScanRDD
                = hBaseUtil.createScanRdd(spark, "Test", scan);

        ScanRDD.mapToPair(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>, String, String>() {


            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> immutableBytesWritableResultTuple2) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }

        });
```

My  ScanRDD.mapToPair function complains that serialversionUid is missing and ask to add one inside `ScanRDD.mapToPair(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>, String, String>() {`

I am wondering why I need to add serialversionUid to my FlatMapFunction ? I have one already for the class.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind that is just a static analysis that verifies that each instance of class that implements Serializable, has `serialVersionUID` field.

In your case FlatMapFunction implements `java.io.Serializable` and you're creating an anonymous class of it.

So just add `serialVersionUID`

```
ScanRDD.mapToPair(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable,Result>, String, String>() {
//inside the anonymous class
private final serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Iterator<String> call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> immutableBytesWritableResultTuple2) throws Exception {
                return null;
}

})
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html